# Data warehouse logical model

Tags: mysql, sql

I have drawn a logical model for a  hotel room booking OLTP system [Logical model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4tAq.png)
I'm facing a problem querying it.
the question is: **For each Country and quarter, produce the cumulative income of 3-star-rooms**
Noted that RoomBand contain how many starts for each room
I have tried this

```
SELECT Quarter, Country
FROM DT_Date, Country, RoomBand
where RoomBand = 3
```

the output was this

```
CountyName  Quarter 
  USA          2
  Uk           1
  USA          2
  UK           1
```

as it has shown it repeated USA and UK
why is that happening
Thanks for the support all

Comment: You are asking why your results look certain way without providing us he source data and the expected results. That's a no go.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score -2):

Try the `DISTINCT` operator with your query. For example: `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-distinct/).

Comment: We do not know enough about the problem to provide an answer. Distinct may or may not be a good solution.